# Julia DifferentialEquations.jl: EnsembleProblem where tspan is varied

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

I am currently working on some ensemble problems where I vary quite a few parameters of an ODE. The ODE in code is given by `sys!` below. It certainly is quite easy to vary the parameters, `w`, `plateu_cycle`, `px` and `py` using the Parallel Ensemble Interface (which even is doable on GPU). However I also need to vary `tspan = [tstart, tend]`, specifically the `tend`. How can I do this? It seems that the EnsembleProblem does not accept variation of `tspan`. The idea will be to paralelly execute all Ensemble Problems on GPU using the `DiffEqGPU.jl` library.

How can I vary `tspan` with parallel execution capability? Is there a specific problem type that I might be missing?
Written code:

```
using DifferentialEquations, PhysicalConstants.CODATA2018

e::Float64 = ElementaryCharge.val
function E_0(w::Float64)
    return w/e
end

function E(px::Float64, py::Float64)
    return sqrt(1+px^2+py^2)
end

function Vectorpotential(t, w::Float64, plateu_cycle::Float64)
    return -E_0(w)/w * sin.(t) * sineSquaredWindow(t,w,plateu_cycle)
end

function sineSquaredWindow(t, w::Float64, plateu_cycle::Float64)
    T = 2pi/w
    if t <= 0
        return 0
    elseif t/w >= 0 && (t/w <= T/2)
        return sin(t/2)^2
    elseif (t / w >= T / 2) && (t / w <= T * (plateu_cycle + 1 / 2))
        return 1
    elseif (t / w >= T * (plateu_cycle + 1 / 2)) & (t / w <= T * (plateu_cycle + 1))
        return 1-sin(w/2 * (t/w - T*(plateu_cycle+1/2)))^2
    end

    return 0
end

function sys!(du, u, params, t)
    w, plateu_cycle, px, py = params
    Energy = E(px,py)
    function nu(t, plateu_cycle::Float64, w::Float64, px::Float64, py::Float64)
        return -1im * e * Vectorpotential(w*t,w,plateu_cycle)*exp(2im*Energy*t) * ( px*py /(Energy*(Energy+1))+1im*(1-py^2 / (Energy*(Energy+1))))
    end
    function kappa(t, plateu_cycle::Float64, w::Float64, py::Float64)
        return 1im*e*Vectorpotential(w*t,w,plateu_cycle)*py/Energy
    end
    du[1] = kappa(t,plateu_cycle,w,py)*u[1] + nu(t, plateu_cycle,w, px,py) *u[2]
    du[2] = -conj(nu(t,plateu_cycle,w,px,py))*u[1] + conj(kappa(t,plateu_cycle,w, py))*u[2]
    return nothing
end 
w = 0.84::Float64
plateu_cycle = 8.0::Float64
px = 0.0
py = 0.0
params=[w, plateu_cycle, px, py]
f0=complex(0.0,0.0)
g0=complex(1.0,0.0)
init_cond = [f0, g0]
tstart = 0
tend = 2pi/w * (plateu_cycle+1)+1
tspan = (tstart, tend)
# this is just en example solve. It does not do the ensemble problems yet
ts = collect(range(tstart, tend, length=1000))
prob = ODEProblem(sys!,init_cond,tspan, params)
sol = solve(prob, Tsit5(), saveat=ts)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I do this? It seems that the EnsembleProblem does not accept variation of tspan.

Have you tried it yet? When you define a `prob_func` you choose the problem per trajectory, and since each problem has a tspan, you just give it a different tspan per trajectory. It's no different from the normal ensemble code.

I cannot modify your code for it because you didn't share an ensemble code, but it would just be exactly like what's shown in the [doc page here](https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/features/ensemble/). For example:

```
function prob_func(prob,i,repeat)
  remake(prob, tspan = (new_tstart, new_tend))
end
```

Comment: I must have missed that. Your code should work just fine (its what I also would do for the "normal" Ensemble problems. I Can not test it right now, as I am not home but I assume this is fine. Thanks and sorry for being blind.

Comment: Had the time to test this now. And it does work. Quite fast even with EnsembleThreads(). It does not with EnsembleGPUArray(). It fails because of a very specific assert that forbids a change of tspan during GPU evaluation. I suppose i can not do much against it since i need to evaluate the ODE each time from 0 until all interaction time has passed (which is when the vectorpotential becomes 0 at the end of the windowfunction and that is dependent on the varied parameter plateu_cycle)

Comment: Yes EnsembleGPUArray has some limitations on the problem definition. EnsembleGPUKernel is a bit faster and does not have this limitation though, so that may be a better fit here.

Comment: I have run into a new Issue with the EnsembleGPUKernel that i made a new question for as this is rather far from this original topic of this question. If you do not mind, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75742366/dynamic-function-invocation-invalidirerror-with-diffeqgpu-ensemblegpukernel